# Insert into subselect slow

Tags: postgresql

I try to fill a table "SAMPLE" that requires ids from three other tables.
The table "SAMPLE" that needs to be filled look holds the following:

- id (integer, not null, pk)
- code (text, not null)
- subsystem_id (integer, fk)
- system_id (integer, not null, fk)
- manufacturer_id (integer, fk)

The current query looks like this:

```
insert into SAMPLE(system_id, manufacturer_id, code, subsystem_id)
values ((select id from system where initial = 'P'), (select id from manufacturer where name = 'nameXY'), 'P0001', (select id from subsystem where code = 'NAME PATTERN'));
```

It is ridiculously slow, inserting 8k rows in around a minute.
I'm not sure if this is a *really* bad query problem or if my postgres configuration is heavily messed up.

For clarification, more table information:
**subsystem:**

- This table holds fixed values (9) with a basic pattern I can access easily.

**system**

- This table holds fixed values (4) that can be identified using the "initial" attribute

**manufacturer**

- This table holds the name of a manufacturer.

The "SAMPLE" table will be the only connection between those tables so I'm not sure if I can use joins.

I'm pretty sure 8k values should be a gigantic joke to insert for a database so I'm really confused.

My specs:
Win 7 x86_64
8GB RAM
intel i5 3470S (QUAD) 2,9 GHZ
Postgres is v9.3

I didn't see any peak during my query so I suspect something is up with my configuration. If you need information about it, let me know.

Note: It is possible that I have codes or names that can not be found in the subsystem or manufacturer tables. Instead of adding nothing, I want to add a NULL value to the cell then.

Comment: `INSERT` probably has nothing to do with it. See how the `SELECT`s perform on their own. Any indexes on the tables you're querying?

Comment: Do you have any trigger or rule on the Sample table? Post the table definition using the command "\d+ Sample" in psql

Comment: I got indexes on the IDs on those tables and indexed the "code" on sample, "initial" on system and "code" on subsystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8000 inserts/mn is roughly 133 per second or 0.133 ms per statement.

This is to be expected if the INSERTs happen in a loop **each statement in its own transaction**.

Each transaction commits to disk and waits for the disk to confirm that the data is written in durable storage. This is known to be slow.

Add a transaction around the loop with BEGIN and END and it will run at normal speed.

Ideally you wouldn't even have a loop but a more complex query that does a single INSERT to create all the rows from their sources, if possible.

Comment: I began to use left outer joins for the problem and it turned out to be good. Speed went from 50sec to 4 sec which is nice.

Couldn't test it with the BEGIN and END clause as pgAdmin told me that I can't do that so I can't tell you that this would have fixed it.

Thanks anyway! :>

Answer (score 0):

I could not test it because I have no PostgreSql installed and no database with a similar structure, but may it would be faster to get the insert data from a single statement

```
INSERT INTO Sample (system_id, manufacturer_id, code, subsystem_id)
SELECT  s.id AS system_id,
        m.id AS manufacturer_id,
        'P0001' AS code,
        ss.id AS subsystem_id
FROM    system s
JOIN    manufacturer m
        ON m.name = 'nameXY'
JOIN    subsystem ss
        ON ss.code = 'NAME PATTERN'
WHERE   s.initial = 'P'
```

I hope this works.

Comment: That doesn't work as some entries can not be found in the subsystem table. I forgot to add that. :s Same with the manufacturer. I don't need to add those manufacturers or subsystems into the tables. I don't want them there as they'd corrupt the logic.

Comment: I think if they does not exist it cannot be inserted at all, as you said `subsystem_id (integer, fk)` and `manufacturer_id (integer, fk)`